# Difficulty reversing a linked list alphabetically

Tags: java

I'm having trouble reversing a LinkedList. In other words, I need them sorted in z-a order (in contrast to a-z). I've tried Collections.reverse but is not coming into effect? I have the following:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class pa9Driver {
//create two list
//1st List is of type word class
//2nd list is of type Anagram_Family
public static List<Word> words = new LinkedList<Word>();
public static List<AnagramFamily> familyList = new LinkedList<AnagramFamily>();

//a main method for driver class
public static void main(String[] args) {
//call the generate method to read word from the file
generate_WordList();
//sort the word list
Collections.sort(words);
//generate the anagram family for the word
generate_FamilyList();
//sort the anagram family list      
Collections.sort(familyList, new anagramFamilyComparator());
//reverse the anagram family list
Collections.reverse(familyList);
topFive();
}//main ends

public static void topFive() {
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
System.out.print(familyList.get(i).getCanonicalForm1() + ", ");
System.out.print(familyList.get(i).getSize() + ": ");
System.out.println(familyList.get(i));
   }
}

//method that read word
public static void generate_WordList() {
File inFile12=new File("words.txt");
Scanner fileRead1=null;
try {
fileRead1 = new Scanner(inFile12);
} catch (Exception exe) {
       exe.printStackTrace();
       System.exit(0);
   }
  
   //until the file has words read the words
   while(fileRead1.hasNext()) {
       words.add(new Word(fileRead1.next()));
   }
}
//generate the anagram and add it to the current family
public static void generate_FamilyList() {
Iterator<Word> readWord1 = words.iterator();
Word previousWord1 = words.get(0);
familyList.add(new AnagramFamily());
int index1 = 0;
while(readWord1.hasNext()) {
Word currentWord1 = readWord1.next();
if(currentWord1.getCanonicalForm1().equals(previousWord1
.getCanonicalForm1())) {
familyList.get(index1).add(currentWord1);
} else {
index1++;
familyList.add(new AnagramFamily());
familyList.get(index1).add(currentWord1);
  }
previousWord1 = currentWord1;
    }
  }
}
```

For convenience sake, I'll only show the first few lines of code that I have and that is expected.
Currently:

> [apers, apres, asper, pares, parse, pears, prase, presa, rapes, reaps, spare, spear]
>
> [alerts, alters, artels, estral, laster, ratels, salter, slater, staler, stelar, talers]

Expected:

> [spear, spare, reaps, rapes, presa, prase, pears, parse, pares, asper, apres, apers]
>
> [talers, stelar, staler, slater, salter, ratels, laster, estral, artels, alters, alerts]

Comment: @shuwnyuantee my code in anagramFamilyComparator is such `import java.util.*;
public class anagramFamilyComparator implements Comparator<AnagramFamily>
{
public int compare(AnagramFamily a, AnagramFamily b)
{
       if(a.getSize() > b.getSize())
{
           return 1;
       }
else if(a.getSize() < b.getSize())
{
           return -1;
       }
else
           return 0;
      
   }
}` I've already tried commenting out `Collections.reverse` but I get an output that is totally changed and irrelevant

Comment: Unreadable un-indented code, and you want us to look at it? --- And don't post code in a comment. Edit the question, insert the extra code you have, and format it for human readability, then us humans might actually look at it.

Comment: It seems your AnagramFamily itself is kind of List and you are not sorting it. You need to sort the Anagram Values as per your desired logic.

Comment: @SahilChhabra you're correct! Thank you for this tip :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Collections.sort(familyList, Comparator.reverseOrder());
```

Alternatively, you can do:

```
Collections.sort(familyList, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                return o2.compareTo(o1);
            }
        });

//Print list in reverse order
        for(String st : familyList){
            System.out.println(st);
        }
```

Comment: The following line spits an error:                         

`pa9Driver.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
       Collections.sort(familyList, Comparator.reverseOrder);
                                              ^
  symbol:   variable reverseOrder
  location: interface Comparator
1 error`

Comment: I've tried reverseOrder() way before I even posted this question, which still spits a "Cannot find symbol" error.

Comment: Where did you get the idea `familyList` is a `List<String>`?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your code, it seems `AnagramFamily` is a kind of `List`, which you are not sorting.

You need to sort the AnagramFamily (List of String) with a `StringComparator` for getting your desired output.

Answer (score -2):

I think you can use compareTo for this action no ? compareTo from Comparable

Comment: Collections.sort(familyList, new Comparator<String>() {
     @Override
     public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
         return Collator.getInstance().compare(o1, o2);
     }

Comment: Haven't learned `Collator` and `getInstance()` so this would be illegal.

Comment: I propose to put a getter at the output of generate_Family and that you will use to assign it to the input of a file that you will create in the hand and with which you will do all your manipulations like sorting, inversion and others.  :)

Comment: could you elaborate on this process?